# Unable to run evosuite

Tags: java, unit-testing, evosuite

I am attempting to run evosuite and getting a `NullPointerException`:

I know what a NullPointerException is, I am asking this question because out-of-the-box, I wouldn't expect this to occur.

###### Command:

```
java -jar evosuite-1.2.0.jar -class example.HelloService -projectCP target/hello-0.0.0.jar
```

###### Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Map.values()" because the return value of "org.evosuite.rmi.service.MasterNodeLocal.getClientsOnceAllConnected(long)" is null
```

I have looked through the [*documentation*](https://www.evosuite.org/documentation/commandline/), but do not see any additional options.

Additionally, I have started to go through the source to see if I can find a workaround.

EDIT: Sample Source below:

```
package example;

public class HelloService {
  public String getMessage(final String name) {
    return "Hi " + name;
  }
}
```

EDIT: Simplified Sample:

```
java -jar evosuite.jar -class HelloService -projectCP .
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, provide a [mre].